# I need it redirect to new page after clicking in listview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, adapter

I am designing a guide application. When I click on the person I selected from the list, it should go to the profile page I prepared. I will be very happy if you can help :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AANpq.png

Comment: Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You're using ListView, which is a type of AdapterView.

You can respond to click events (in this case same thing as tap events) by registering an `onItemClickListener` as described [here in the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#HandlingUserSelections):

```
listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
    val user: UserDto = adapter.getItem(position)
    //start new Activity through Intent here
}
```

You combine the information about the currently presented `UserDto`s from your adapter with the `OnItemClickListener` `position` parameter to get the `UserDto` whose view the user clicked on.

You'll then want to start a new Intent, passing the user information to the new activity with the extra information that Intents can hold. The Android developer documentation [has an example for something similar too](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#CreateActivity).

Comment: I try but I can't. Can you give me a social media address where I can reach you? I need to finish this app urgently.